# How to get Google+ App permission status

Tags: google-plus

I'm operting a website, which enables users to login via facebook or/and google+ to access their user profile. If a  user logs in with facebook, I want to show if the user also granted permissions to log in via Google+.

I have an G+ access- and refresh token in a database. I've tried to use the G+ client's "setAccessToken()" function and afterwards "isAccessTokenExpired()" to do a check. The problem is that "setAccessToken()" expects the accessToken param as a JSON string (the same you receive as you log in with google+). So I think that's not the way to go...

Does anyone has an idea how to check if the user granted permissions to log in (without logging in)?

Best regards
ninsky

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but I've used a refresh token to check if I can get a new access token. If that fails, the user revoked access.

Answer (score 1):

You're not specifying the library you're using (if any), but most of the Google-provided libraries require that the access_token object that was returned (which contains both the access_token and the refresh_token, along with other values) be the one that is passed to the API for authentication. In general, best practice is to store the entire JSON object and not the individual values in it.